# Check if any radiobutton of an group is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this JS code to check if any radiobutton per line checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_add_table_1()
{
    // maatv
    if (document.getElementsByName('maatv').checked = false) {
        document.getElementById('maatv_glyp').className = ""; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('maatv_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"; }

    // lassen
    if (document.getElementsByName('lassen').checked = false) {
        document.getElementById('lassen_glyp').className = ""; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('lassen_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"; }
}
</script>
```

For some reason, when I choose the top row, JS is also setting the OK sign for the second line.
[image]

Any suggestions?

```
<tr>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $lang['maatv']; ?>:</td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="maatv" value="uitstekend"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="maatv" value="goed"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="maatv" value="voldoende"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="maatv" value="matig"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="maatv" value="slecht"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="maatv" value="nvt"></td>
    <td align="center"><span id="maatv_glyp" class="" style="color:green"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $lang['lassen']; ?>:</td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="lassen" value="uitstekend"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="lassen" value="goed"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="lassen" value="voldoende"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="lassen" value="matig"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="lassen" value="slecht"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1()" type="radio" name="lassen" value="nvt"></td>
    <td align="center"><span id="lassen_glyp" class="" style="color:green"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `.getElementsByName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object, that object doesn't have `checked` property untill you explicitly set it (to `false`) in the `if`conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just split the group of buttons into their own `onChange` functions. From your example, I split the two `if-else` statements into their own functions and cleaned up the code a bit with correct javascript usage on some of your elements. Instead of getting a NodeList of objects the previous way you have you code, I changed it to just use `this` to select the current object that is selected. I also used `setAttribute` to set the checkmark's class names.

JS:

```
<script>
function validate_add_table_1(temp)
{
    // maatv
     var maatvCheckMark = document.getElementById('maatv_glyp');
    if (temp.checked === false) {
         maatvCheckMark.setAttribute('class','') }
    else {
        maatvCheckMark.setAttribute('class','glyphicon glyphicon-ok'); }
}

function validate_add_table_2(temp2)
{
    // lassen
    var lassenCheckMark =  document.getElementById('lassen_glyp');
    if (temp2.checked === false) {
        lassenCheckMark.setAttribute('class',''); }
    else {
        lassenCheckMark.setAttribute('class','glyphicon glyphicon-ok'); }
}
</script>
```

Html:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $lang['maatv']; ?>:</td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1(this)" type="radio" name="maatv" value="uitstekend"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1(this)" type="radio" name="maatv" value="goed"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1(this)" type="radio" name="maatv" value="voldoende"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1(this)" type="radio" name="maatv" value="matig"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1(this)" type="radio" name="maatv" value="slecht"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_1(this)" type="radio" name="maatv" value="nvt"></td>
    <td align="center"><span id="maatv_glyp" class="" style="color:green"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $lang['lassen']; ?>:</td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_2(this)" type="radio" name="lassen" value="uitstekend"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_2(this)" type="radio" name="lassen" value="goed"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_2(this)" type="radio" name="lassen" value="voldoende"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_2(this)" type="radio" name="lassen" value="matig"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_2(this)" type="radio" name="lassen" value="slecht"></td>
    <td align="center"><input onchange="validate_add_table_2(this)" type="radio" name="lassen" value="nvt"></td>
    <td align="center"><span id="lassen_glyp" class="" style="color:green"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thx, I hope to avoid splitting up the code in different statements but it seemed the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

That is because your if-statements are wrong.

```
if (document.getElementsByName('lassen').checked == false) {
```

You need to compare it with **==**

You are using = that's why it will always go into the else branch on both if statements.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('maatv')` does not have `checked`.

Comment: @connexo You mean the object does not have the param checked? Checkboxobjects always have the param checked which returns false or true.

Comment: @davidev Sure they have, but [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) doesn't return a "_checkbox object_".

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant You are totally right. Didn't see it. getElement will return only one. When fetching multiple you might wanna cycle through all with a loop or how would you approach?

Comment: `document.querySelector('[name="maatv"]:checked')` would be my choise.

Comment: Great one @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant Totally overlooked that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple vanilla Javascript example:

```js
document.querySelector('.radiogroups').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const anyChecked = [...event.target.parentElement.querySelectorAll('input')]
    .some(radio => radio.checked);
  event.target.parentElement.querySelector('.result').textContent = anyChecked;
})
```

```html
<div class="radiogroups">
    <div class="radiogroup">
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        <span class="result">false</span>
    </div>
    <div class="radiogroup">
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        <span class="result">false</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the same example with checkboxes:

```js
document.querySelector('.checkboxgroups').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const anyChecked = [...event.target.parentElement.querySelectorAll('input')]
    .some(checkbox => checkbox.checked);
  event.target.parentElement.querySelector('.result').textContent = anyChecked;
})
```

```html
<div class="checkboxgroups">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="row1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row1" />
        <span class="result">false</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="row2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="row2" />
        <span class="result">false</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cono = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
Array.from(cono).forEach(function(e){
  var cono2 = e.getElementsByTagName('input');
  Array.from(cono2).forEach(function(b){
    b.addEventListener('change', function(){
      if(b.checked == true){
      b.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("withicon")
    }
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.icon{
  display:none
}

tr.withicon .icon{
  display:unset
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
      <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="maatv" value="uitstekend"></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="maatv" value="goed"></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="maatv" value="voldoende"></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="maatv" value="matig"></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="maatv" value="slecht"></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="maatv" value="nvt"></td>
  <td align="center"><span class="icon">ICON HERE</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="lassen" value="uitstekend"></td>
  <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="lassen" value="goed"></td>
  <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="lassen" value="matig"></td>
  <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="lassen" value="slecht"></td>
  <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="lassen" value="uitstekend"></td>
  <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="lassen" value="nvt"></td>
  <td align="center"><span class="icon">ICON HERE</span></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to point here:

1. Your if statement is missing the == check.
2. document.getElementsByName("someName") doesn't contain checked property instead it return NodeList object

> The getElementsByName() method of the Document object returns a NodeList Collection of elements with a given name in the document.

So instead of checking like `if(document.getElementsByName('maatv').checked == false)` you might want to check on `NodeList` object, whether if any of it's element checked property is true or not.

Something like this:

```js
function isRadioSelected(name){
  let resultElem = Array.from(document.getElementsByName(name)).find((item) => item.checked);
  
  // Just for display purpose
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultElem ? resultElem.checked : false;
  
  //return resultElem ? resultElem.checked : false; return the result from here
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="colors" >Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="colors" >Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="colors" >green<br>
<button onclick="isRadioSelected('colors')"> Check </button>

<label id="result"></label>
```

And use function `isRadioSelected(name)` in your `if` condition something like this:

```
if (!isRadioSelected('maatv')) {
        document.getElementById('maatv_glyp').className = ""; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('maatv_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"; }
```

I hope this helps.